# Unable to open anything except gnome

Tags: gnome, kde, 22.04

I recently upgraded to 22.04. I used to have kde plasma before, I switched back to gnome but it still shows the plasma login screen when I open the PC and does not let me switch to Wayland or xorg. When I do it shows a blank screen and I have to force a shut down. Also it shows a weird plasma like taskbar but no dock. If this is important I have dual booted Ubuntu with windows.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, your goal is to switch the display manager (DM), from kddm (of KDE) back to gdm3 (of gnome3).

You can check [this](https://trendoceans.com/how-to-remove-the-kde-plasma-environment-in-ubuntu/) for a reference. Steps 5-6 should give you a hint. If the DM does not run automatically after reboot (i.e. only a terminal shows when booting), don't panic. Try reinstalling gdm3 and `enable` and `start` it again (as in step 6).

Problems regarding your graphic card driver may also appear. If so, you can try to reinstall the graphic card driver.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.

Comment: It worked for everything except the login gui do you have any idea how I can fix that also it still doesn't let me switch giving me a blank screen if i try to.

Comment: Ok i had to use sudo permission for the systemctl it's working now thx